# changing a programmatically made UIButton to UILabel within certain textFields or stackViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

Beginner Swift programmer here and new to stack overflow.

I am trying to make a simple task list/toDoPlanner, kinda similar to Apple's reminders app on the iPhone.

My goal is for this specific problem is that when a user clicks on the UIButton within a certain textField (which is within a stackView), that UIButton should change to a UILabel.

Here is how I make a button appear after a user finishes typing a task. This works fine:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    if(textField == textField1) // if the first text field is pressed
    {
        let image = UIImage(named: "To Be Completed Circle.png")
        button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 340, y: 56, width: 30, height: 30));
        button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
...
```

And then here is how I am trying to change the UIButton when the user clicks it to change that button into a UILabel:

```
func pressed(textField: UITextField!) {


    let image = UIImage(named: "Checkmark.png")
    if(textField == textField1)
    {
        button.removeFromSuperview()
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x : 340, y :56, width: 30, height: 30))
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
```

The whole if block isn't being read, and I am not too sure why. I am assuming it has to do with separate properties of the UIButton and the UITextField.

Any help is appreciated and any other tips for programming in iOS is helpful!

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: You could easily just do button.isEnabled = false to achieve similar effect. Or hide and show the button and/or label accordingly.  Both options should work.

Comment: What I am trying to do is a user types in a "task" on the first text field. After pressing return, a grey circle will appear (button) next to the task. I want the user to be able to click this button which will change the grey circle into a grey circle with a red checkmark (label), signifying the task has been completed. Does this clarify what I am trying to do?

Comment: I would keep it a button and change the image associated with the button. This way every time they tap the button it would toggle between checked and unchecked.

Comment: @rMickeyD How would I go about changing the images associated with a certain button?

Answer (score 0):

Your textField is not associated with the button, even though you are creating it with the textFieldShouldReturn function. So your target (self.pressed) does not receive any textField parameter, and will be nil. Thus, your textField == textField1 will never be true.

If you're implementing a task list, an easier way would be to add each new task to a tableView. Then you would be able to associate a button and label (For the task name) with a section & row.

It would also be much easier to change the image of the button instead of removing it and creating a UILabel in it's place.

Comment: i gotcha. Is there any way though I can get textField == textField1 to be true through this way?